# Dynamically change overlay of HTTP stream

Tags: streaming, open-source, vlc, http-live-streaming

I need to http stream a source file (*.ts) with a logo or subtitle track, that can dynamically be changed (on server side) during run-time. The stream will be viewed on an iPad. A static logo is quite easy to implement with VLC, however not a dynamic one...

I found an old VLC wiki page were this is described for logo changing:

```
vlc -I rc --logo-file nonexistent_dummy.png --sout "#transcode{vcodec=...,vb=...,sfilter=logo}:duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{...}}"

# Once the program has started
add video.avi
# If using VLC 0.9.0 or newer (see NEWS for details about the new syntax):
@logo logo-file logo.png
```

It seems that the `@logo` command was removed in the more recent versions of RC Interface. Is it possible to change logo filter during run time by another Interface or the standard GUI?

Is there any other free or open source solutions to stream and change overlay during run-time? 
Thank you.